# SQL return consecutive records

Tags: sql, linq, lambda, sql-server-2008-r2

A simple table:

```
ForumPost
--------------
ID (int PK)
UserID (int FK)
Date (datetime)
```

What I'm looking to return how many times a particular user has made at least 1 post a day for *n* consecutive days.

Example:

```
User 15844 has posted at least 1 post a day for 30 consecutive days 10 times
```

I've tagged this question with linq/lambda as well as a solution there would also be great.  I know I can solve this by iterating all the users records but this is slow.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: use a subquery for all posts in date range of 30 days prior, group by date and count.. check if 30?

Comment: related, maybe duplicate: [Calculating Consecutive Absences in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557067/calculating-consecutive-absences-in-sql)

Comment: @FuzzyButton - if they posted 30 times on one day and 29 days had  no posts, and the total would still be 30.

Comment: It depends a little on what "30 consecutive days 10 times" means. If you post every day between 2013-01-01 and 2013-01-30, that's 30 consecutive days, 1 time. If you post again on 2013-01-31, is that 30 consecutive days 2 times?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever - that's why I said `GROUP BY date` and then `COUNT` :)  ... count the number of days with posts in the range.

Answer (score 4):

There is a handy trick you can use using `ROW_NUMBER()` to find consecutive entries, imagine the following set of dates, with their row_number (starting at 0):

```
Date        RowNumber
20130401    0
20130402    1
20130403    2
20130404    3
20130406    4
20130407    5
```

For consecutive entries if you subtract the row_number from the value you get the same result. e.g.

```
Date        RowNumber   date - row_number
20130401    0           20130401
20130402    1           20130401
20130403    2           20130401
20130404    3           20130401
20130406    4           20130402
20130407    5           20130402
```

You can then group by `date - row_number` to get the sets of consecutive days (i.e. the first 4 records, and the last 2 records).

To apply this to your example you would use:

```
WITH Posts AS
(   SELECT  FirstPost = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]),
            UserID,
            Date
    FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT UserID, [Date] = CAST(Date AS [Date])
                FROM    ForumPost
            ) fp
), Posts2 AS
(   SELECT  FirstPost, 
            UserID, 
            Days = COUNT(*), 
            LastDate = MAX(Date)
    FROM    Posts
    GROUP BY FirstPost, UserID
)
SELECT  UserID, ConsecutiveDates = MAX(Days)
FROM    Posts2
GROUP BY UserID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle (simple with just most consecutive days per user)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9db9/3)**

**[Further example to show how to get all consecutive periods](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9db9/4)**

**EDIT**

I don't think the above quite answered the question, this will give the number of times a user has posted on, or over n consecutive days:

```
WITH Posts AS
(   SELECT  FirstPost = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]),
            UserID,
            Date
    FROM    (   SELECT  DISTINCT UserID, [Date] = CAST(Date AS [Date])
                FROM    ForumPost
            ) fp
), Posts2 AS
(   SELECT  FirstPost, 
            UserID, 
            Days = COUNT(*), 
            FirstDate = MIN(Date), 
            LastDate = MAX(Date)
    FROM    Posts
    GROUP BY FirstPost, UserID
)
SELECT  UserID, [Times Over N Days] = COUNT(*)
FROM    Posts2
WHERE   Days >= 30
GROUP BY UserID;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d72f0/4)**

Answer (score 1):

Your particular application makes this pretty simple, I think. If you have 'n' distinct dates in an 'n'-day interval, those 'n' distinct dates *must* be consecutive.

Scroll to the bottom for a general solution that requires only common table expressions and changing to PostgreSQL. (Kidding. I implemented in PostgreSQL, because I'm short of time.)

```
create table ForumPost (
  ID integer primary key,
  UserID integer not null,
  post_date date not null
);

insert into forumpost values
(1, 1, '2013-01-15'),
(2, 1, '2013-01-16'),
(3, 1, '2013-01-17'),
(4, 1, '2013-01-18'),
(5, 1, '2013-01-19'),
(6, 1, '2013-01-20'),
(7, 1, '2013-01-21'),

(11, 2, '2013-01-15'),
(12, 2, '2013-01-16'),
(13, 2, '2013-01-17'),
(16, 2, '2013-01-17'),
(14, 2, '2013-01-18'),
(15, 2, '2013-01-19'),

(21, 3, '2013-01-17'),
(22, 3, '2013-01-17'),
(23, 3, '2013-01-17'),
(24, 3, '2013-01-17'),
(25, 3, '2013-01-17'),
(26, 3, '2013-01-17'),
(27, 3, '2013-01-17');
```

Now, let's look at the output of this query. For brevity, I'm looking at 5-day intervals, not 30-day intervals.

```
select userid, count(distinct post_date) distinct_dates
from forumpost
where post_date between '2013-01-15' and '2013-01-19'
group by userid;

USERID  DISTINCT_DATES  
1       5
2       5
3       1
```

For users that fit the criteria, the number of distinct dates in that 5-day interval will have to be 5, right?  So we just need to add that logic to a HAVING clause.

```
select userid, count(distinct post_date) distinct_dates
from forumpost
where post_date between '2013-01-15' and '2013-01-19'
group by userid
having count(distinct post_date) = 5;

USERID  DISTINCT_DATES  
1       5
2       5
```

---

**A more general solution**

It doesn't really make sense to say that, if you post every day from 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31, you've posted 30 consecutive days 2 times. Instead, I'd expect the clock to start over on 2013-01-31. My apologies for implementing in PostgreSQL; I'll try to implement in T-SQL later.

```
with first_posts as (
  select userid, min(post_date) first_post_date
  from forumpost
  group by userid
), 
period_intervals as (
  select userid, first_post_date period_start, 
         (first_post_date + interval '4' day)::date period_end
  from first_posts
), user_specific_intervals as (
  select 
    userid, 
    (period_start + (n || ' days')::interval)::date as period_start, 
    (period_end + (n || ' days')::interval)::date as period_end 
  from period_intervals, generate_series(0, 30, 5) n
)
select userid, period_start, period_end, 
       (select count(distinct post_date) 
        from forumpost
        where forumpost.post_date between period_start and period_end
          and userid = forumpost.userid) distinct_dates
from user_specific_intervals
order by userid, period_start;
```